# Integrating apache-kafka client with java application as log appender

Tags: log4j, appender, apache-kafka

Is someone aware of any opensource implementation of Log4J appender which can write log events to Kafka?

Answer (score 3):

There is a KafkaLog4jAppender already included in the Kafka project.

You'll find the api docs to that here: http://people.apache.org/~joestein/kafka-0.7.1-incubating-docs/kafka/producer/KafkaLog4jAppender.html (for 0.7.1)

and the corresponding source code here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.7.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/producer/KafkaLog4jAppender.scala

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned that I wish to use it in an application developed in Java.

Comment: Scala compiles down to Java bytecode so it works perfectly well to use the KafkaLog4jAppender in a Java application. I´m not aware of any Log4jAppender that can write to Kafka developed in pure Java but maybe there is such a thing.